# Adding Volley dependency to a java library project in android studio

Tags: java, android, rest, http

I have created a java library project module to keep all the REST api consumption logic in a separate module. Now can I use http rest libraries like Volley, Retrofit, OkHttp, Ion etc in this module without any problems?

**EDIT**

I have added the [github koush/Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion) library, I am developing currently with it, I want to know if I were to use this library on some other device other than android would it still work?

Comment: I think so, have you tried it?

Comment: @abbath I have added the github koush/Ion library, I am developing currently, I want to know if I were to use this library on some other device other than android would it still work?

Comment: ah, so a simple java application? I think Volley is designed for only Android.

Comment: yes like some java application in Linux or something

Comment: @abbath so if i wanted to build an api SDK in java that i could use for android as well other jvms what should i do?